What would spacecraft be like if outer space was filled with blood?
In my Earth, outer space is filled entirely with a mysterious blood-like substance, having the same physical properties of blood with the exception that it doesn't clot or evaporate. Barriers exist on the planet that prevents 'outer space' from leaking into the world. The barrier is a one-way passage so those on the planet within can get past the barrier with no issues but those outside cannot. Strangely, the depth pressure of the blood remains at a constant 44,444 kPa no matter where. The solar system is still the same in orbit, gravity, etc. despite the presence of the blood.
My Earth humans know about all of this but they still want to try landing a spaceship on the moon. They're sure the moon also has a similar barrier to their Earth.
What would their spacecraft be like? In other words, how would they design their spaceship with their outer space's properties in mind?

Obviously, the would-be astronauts are doomed, given that they can't pass back through the barrier to a world.  However, the interplanetary medium would be a lot like water, but apparently transparent.  A submarine, perhaps?

Do you really mean that the pressure is almost half that at the bottom of the Mariana Trench, or is the comma indicating a decimal?  Given the parameters of "outer space", you need to provide more information on how bodies in "outer space" work.  For example, they can't be orbiting each other because of the density of the viscous fluid (so it can't be a "moon") and light cannot travel any significant distance without being absorbed (so no sunlight and how do they know the moon exists).

I can't bring myself to VTC because the question meets the basic expectations - but -1 for not thinking the question through before asking it. You're trying to travel through a fluid? @MontyWild's right... submarine. All other details are just engineering. I suspect this was more of a "huh, I'm just curious" question. If that's the case, please remember the [help/dont-ask] prohibits questions that are "mindless social fun." Thanks.

@KerrAvon2055 No misplaced commas.

If it has all the physical properties of blood, how would we even know there's a moon? Or a sun? How would Earth support not only life but human life with no sunlight?

Among the innumerable other issues, with a liquid medium between earth and the sun, I’m pretty sure just the noise of the sun would be fatal.

Impossible to traverse
Travelling through a fluid at the specified pressure requires something along the lines of DSV Limiting Factor, which has been used for the majority of descents into Challenger Deep.  As can be seen in the linked specifications, it can travel at 1 or 2 knots for 96 hours.  However, let's be very generous and assume that it can travel at a whole 15 knots for 100 hours.  That will let it travel 1500 nautical miles... or less than 1% of the distance to the moon.  Put another way, in order to make a one-way trip it is necessary to engineer a deep space submersible with 10 times the speed and over 100 times the endurance of the best deep-sea submersible that exists today.  That is very difficult.
However, that's trivially easy compared to getting the space-submersible started in the bloodspace.  In order to do that, the (very large and heavy) space-submersible must be lifted up through the atmosphere by some kind of rocket with the opposite problem to today's space launch vehicles.  Instead of going sideways really quickly to attain orbital speed, the rocket must lift the space-submersible straight up and slow down to practically zero as it reaches the barrier - because if the space-submersible travels through the barrier and impacts "water" at multiple-kilometre depth pressures at more than a few knots entry speed it will resemble a pancake.
Except that the OP has said that everything is still orbiting the same way it does when space is filled with vacuum.  Which means that Earth is being magically pushed through the bloodspace at almost 30 km per second as it orbits the sun.  Nothing we humans can make is going to survive being pushed into the turbulence of bloodspace passing at 30 km per second, not to mention that the puny 15 knot top speed will make it unable to make any headway.  In fact, it will be completely unable to match speed with the moon, which is hurtling around the Earth at 1 km/sec while also travelling around the sun at the same speed as the Earth.
Finally, if the difficult, extremely difficult and completely impossible limitations are all overcome, it will apparently encounter an impassable barrier around the moon and be unable to land.

Is sending the ship into the wake of our 30kps orbit better or worse than trying to head through the impact eye as our planet hits bloodspace? I'm guessing neither is what you'd call easily survivable but is there an orbital insertion window that's better than others?

@Ash it's impossible to model with real-world physics because the bloodspace doesn't follow real-world phase transitions - it can't evaporate which means it somehow remains liquid as a massive body is constantly ploughing through it at 30 km/s.  (Let's not even think about the energies involved in Mercury with its faster orbital speed!)  Even if the wake would allow the spacemersible to gradually match speeds over more than 150 seconds (which is a very long time), that's still an average acceleration of over 20G, which is not survivable for more than a fraction of a second.

Ouch, right I hadn't thought about the G forces, messy.

of course, you don't need to send humans on rockets, since stuff can't come back, you can just put somthing solid out there using rockets and use it as an achor to lift things up. extremely easy space elevators.

@John that's a really interesting idea, consider developing it into an answer.  OP has not specified the height of the one-way barrier, but if it's low then it may not require the extreme material strength required for an elevator to geostationary.  Whether an object can be partially pushed through the barrier is unclear and the "anchor" would still be buffeted and moved by the extreme bloodspace turbulence, still worth writing up.

Frame Challenge
Given the almost full spectrum opacity of blood they cannot in fact see the Sun let alone have the Moon reflect any of it's light and be visible. Given the distance even the UV, X-ray and Gamma output of the Sun is going to be muted-to-invisible. The humans of this setting do not in fact have astronomy at all and no definite target to their explorations. They may wish to see what, if anything, lies behind the all enveloping red sky and thus have some reason to try launching anyway but "going to the Moon" is not a mission goal.
That is assuming that there is some kind of light, and heat, effect that is permeating this strange reality that is allowing the existence of people on the planet at all.

Probably they don't.
Underwater travel at pressures such as the one you specify moves at a few knots at most. The distance to the moon is about 380,000 km. Travel time would come out to several years, and we cannot build a submarine capable of continuous travel for such a long time.
Except that you did specify that orbits remain the same. If that applies to spacecraft as well as well as planets and moons, immediately after passing the barrier the spacecraft will run into a wall of liquid to wreck it. No time to run out of spare barts.
There were theories and some good stories about something called luminiferous aether and what it means for space travel (i.e. sailing in space). The aether was described as thin and not interacting with normal matter, otherwise it would have been quite impossible.

:-) Can you imagine the mess caused by lunar, planetary, and stellar orbits at speed through blood? I'm almost giggling over what a pulsar would sound like in this circumstance. FWA-huoomf BWOAHP blurp!

@JBH Maybe the shield around the planet is like some sort of repulsor that just moves the blood around so motion of planets is uninhibited. Then spaceflight would come down to building a smaller shield, though I’m not sure why that would even be useful when the upper surface of the shield is filled with ultra-luxury novelty ocean liners sailing on the ceiling of the world…

@controlgroup You're not wrong! But the more we assume ways to make the OP's question rational the more we reduce the blood to the density of a vacuum. Nope, I'm taking Dmyt at his/her word... planets moving through blood at speed. We'll ignore how the shockwave caused by Earth's orbit would throw the moon out of the proverbial soup bowl! :-) Although... the bow shock of the Earth might be enough to throw the blood far enough away from the planet for the moon to orbit freely in a vacuum. This harks back to the infamous spoons question.

@controlgroup, it would make spaceflight the art of calculating currents and catching the ride. "Let's ride the Jupiter tide to Mars."

No shock waves, or waves of any sort, because the pressure is constant. Which would mean no resistance to travel because the pressure on all sides of the ship would be the same. Which is in direct contradiction to the description of the fluid as having the same physical properties as blood, which would include things like viscosity and density...I think this question needs to be fundamentally rethought and defined in much more detail.
